# changing my combobox list to number so i can insert it to database c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, combobox, selecteditem

i wanna do a combobox for the classes , when i insert the type of class in it i want to selecteditem the row that was selected exmple: i chose second row then i insert to the database a 2

```
               sql = "insert into etudiant  (Nom, prenom, sexe,classess) " +
                    "values(@Nom, @prenom,  @sexe,@classess)"/*+"class (nom_class)" + "values(@nom_class) "*/;
                   cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
               cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenom", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexe", bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text);

               int id = comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classess",Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));//*/

               //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Num", bunifuMaterialTextbox6.Text);
               //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Classess", bunifuMaterialTextbox7.Text);
               int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i couldn't find a way to do it like that
i wanna find a way so i can insert to table classes int  for the number of that row like the ID

Comment: Hoe are you populating the combobox? What value are you getting in `combobox1.SelectedItem`? What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: Also specify if you are in WPF/Winforms or what!
Why not using the selectedvalue item of the combo?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya from this  ``````   conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            sql = @"select * from  class";
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());


            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
               comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["nom_class"].ToString());
                

            }
            conn.Close();`````` and @emanuele it's Winforms

Comment: What the issue you are facing?

Comment: Well the probleme that i have that i wanna put each line in my combobox a number to insert it to database for example when i chose in combobox country i chose england i insert in the database a number 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, you would like to achieve the current combobox selected index and insert

it into your database.

First, I want to mention that you should use comboBox1.SelectedIndex instead of   comboBox1.SelectedItem.

Second, I use `sqlconnection` to complete the same operation, so you can modify the following code to apply to your code.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstr = @"";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "insert into Example(Nom,Prenom,Sexe,Classess) values(@Nom,@Prenom,@Sexe,@Classess)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenom", textBox2.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexe", textBox3.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classess", comboBox1.SelectedIndex+1);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("add value successfully"); 

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("class1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("class2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("class3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("class4");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank u so much it worked i willuse selectedindex next time :)

Comment: @YassineFatnassi, I am glad that my solution is working for you. I suggest that you can mark it as answer, thanks.